# MongoDB and PHPCR-ODM

Tags: symfony, symfony-cmf

I used PHPCR-ODM with Jackalope / Doctrine-DBAL implementation so far on my Symfony2 website. However, now I'm considering using MongoDB instead of the mentioned one as a content repository, hopefully with PHPCR-ODM layer.

How much does it take to replace these DB "engines"? What am I supposed to take into account when doing this? What are the requirements from me? Any suggestions and recommendations are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an early attempt at a mongodb binding for jackalope: https://github.com/jackalope/jackalope-mongodb

If you get that to work, you won't see any difference on the PHPCR-ODM layer. Why do you want to replace the database layer? Regardless of storage, the database representation is not suitable for direct access (SQL queries or the like).

Comment: Thx. I have some performance concerns. AFAIK this jackalope-mongodb is "in production" for at least 2 years now? Also, the latest commit (more than a year ago) suggests it's a "dead" project. It's not good for any more serious project, I can't use it. As an alternative I consider using Java's Jackrabbit or sth like that (using Java is ok to me). Any other recommendation then instead of MongoDB?

Comment: yep, as i said "early attempt". the readme clearly states its not production ready. it would take some serious effort and testing to get the jackalope-mongodb to a state that you would want to use it. regarding performance, for smaller data sets we saw that dbal is faster than jackrabbit. if you expect large data sets or concurrent writes, jackrabbit will be better. if you don't know yet, you could also start with dbal and switch to jackrabbit when the traffic grows.